# Using variables defined in functions.php WORDPRESS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a variable that is being pulled from a jQuery into php in my functions.php file.

But I'm unable to use it in a page.

When I echo it from functions.php, it appears in the console in chrome, but has a 0 appended..

If I try to echo it in my template page, I get nothing.

Code below.

jQuery

```
var pie = 131;

$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl, //super global supplied by Wordpress; do not change
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        action: 'get_post_id', //this is correct
            pie : pie 
    },
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

functions.php

```
    add_action('wp_head','pluginname_ajaxurl');
    function pluginname_ajaxurl() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_id', 'my_ajax_function' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_post_id', 'my_ajax_function' );

    function my_ajax_function() {
        $new_pie = isset($_POST['pie']) ? $_POST['pie'] : false;
        echo($new_pie);
    }
```

template-page.php

```
    <?php echo($new_pie); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *sidenote:* brackets in `echo` is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed this in a previous question of yours.

The 0 is being appended to the Ajax call because you need to `die()` after the echo.

```
echo $new_pie;
die();
```

This will stop the `0` from being appended.

As for the return of the data from the AJAX call, you need to do something with it, like append it to an element.

```
$('#elementID').append(data);
```

Which in this case, `elementID` is the ID of an element such as a DIV or P.

**sidenote**

There's no reason to use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

Wordpress has created the javascript `ajaxurl` variable for you and has been doing so since WP 2.8.

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry, I had been checking the previous question, but didn't see your responses.

Cool, 0 sorted.

I need to use the var $new_pie as a variable in my page, for pulling in custom fields, dependent on the value passed.

    <?php the_field('option_4_description', $new_pie); ?>

Is that possible?

@Ohgodwhy

Comment: @DeanMGordon Nope, you would use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Getting_Custom_Fields) instead. Hint. You can do `global $post; $post->ID;` to get the current ID of the post you're on.

Comment: ah alas, I shall keep thinking then.
Thanks for all your help. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Note that the `ajaxurl` you're mentioning is only available in the dashboard. If you're using ajax on the front end, you need to declare it. And you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) for that.